# Different citation styles for different bibliographies in multibib

Tags: bibliographies, multibib

I have a document with two bibliographies using bibtex and multibib.  Like so:

```
\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{A}{Other References}
```

I use the usual `\cite` command for the other bibliography.  This gives me references like [1], [2], [3], from `\cite` and [A1], [A2], etc from `\citeA`.  This works fine.

However what I really want is references like [1], [2], [3], from `\cite` and [A], [B], [C], etc from `\citeA`.  What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there any news here? With the modern package biblatex, that wouldn't be a big deal.